# PHP Secure Authentication Which Lives Forever

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication, authorization

I am planning to write a javascript plugin which will be placed on few different websites. The plugin say bookmarks the current visited website to my database against current logged in user.

The user of my website can login with their username/email and password. Now I want to store an access token that will never expire in cookie of user's browser so every time s/he click on the plugin bookmark button, the javascript will grab cookie and send the request to server with it so server know who user generated it.

My question is, what is the secure way to do that? I can simply store user id in cookie but that's really very easy to simulate by any user. If I encrypt the user id with MD5 hash, the hash would be same every time user login and can act as a user id so not a solution. What solution would you recommend me? Please also write me the link to its algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Some sort of [Challenge-Response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge-response_authentication) protocol based on data stored in the browser - perhaps using [localStorage or domStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) on the browser to store a key, which is combined cryptographically with the "challenge" from the server to respond with a "response" hash - which when verified by the server allows the user to progress.

That wouldn't secure the user's browser, but would make it difficult for an outside observer (who can somehow defeat SSL -- you should be using HTTPS!) to perform a replay attack.

Example protocol: [Secure Remote Password Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_remote_password_protocol) ([JavaScript implementation](http://www.clipperz.com/open_source/javascript_crypto_library) of the client-side)

Comment: Updated _localStorage_ link to MDN.

Comment: @David, if you were me, and you had to store something in cookie that identifies user and that lives forever at user's computer unless explicit logout is made or cookies are deleted, what would you store? and what algorithm would you use to encrypt that data before storing that assures maximum security?

Comment: What you store (a very large number will suffice) isn't important. If the attacker can break open the user's browser, the game is over. This approach just stops an all powerful eavesdropper from pretending to be *your* user from a different browser.

Comment: Any of the example links in the Wikipedia article should be fine :-)

Comment: So you mean there is no way to keep user always logged in assuring security?

Comment: Added a link to an example protocol.

Comment: No I didn't say that, I just said that if the attacker can physically control your user's browser - all bets are off. A real-world analogy: you secure your house key in your pocket. If someone breaks into your pocket, they have your key -- if they also know your address, there's nothing anyone can do (short of men with guns) to assuredly secure it :-) This protocol just stops someone from taking an X-ray picture of you walking by in order to make a duplicate key.

Comment: But how can I store something that can not be decrypted by anyone other than the server?

Comment: Read the links above about Challenge-Response. You don't send the stored key - instead you send something _generated_ using that key, combined with _different_ info given to the user's broweser on each load (by the server).

Comment: OK so if I don't send the key but something generated with that key and assuming I am using JavaScript to generate that "something", I am still not secure. JavaScript code executes at the client.

Comment: There's nothing _any_ software, of _any_ kind, running on _any_ platform can do to be more secure than that. I think you've got this idea of browser security that doesn't quite mesh with reality :-)..... and it should't just be generated in any old way, there are algorithms - linked above - that describe how to do so leaking 'zero knowledge'.

Comment: Here's simple question. How Google and Facebook does that? How I don't logout of Facebook and everyday I visit it, it's opened?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9371/discussion-between-umair-ashraf-and-david-skymesh)